# Field depends on another field's answer in a survey form

Tags: jquery, mysql, forms, jquery-validate, survey

I've been trying to solve this problem for days.. I have to make an online survey, the form is loaded dynamically depending on some previous choices by the user.. which means I can't use the "name" or "id" attributes of the inputs because they are not always the same. I'm using the Jquery validate plugin to make all inputs required and it works fine. But my problem is :

- Some questions depend on the response of the previous question, which means not only that the previous question should be answered but a specific answer. (Example:" do you like fruits ?" if the answer is "Yes" then show another question "which of these fruits do you  usually eat?" and make it required, if the answer is "No" don't show the question at all.

I thought I'd add a field "depend" in the database Questions table to make some questions depending of others, but then the type of the dependance is different from one question to another.

This would be very easy if I had a static form, but it's not.

Please help!

Comment: Are you using PHP at all for it?

Comment: yes I'm using Ajax to load the form, and then PHP to fill the form dynamically with the appropriate fields

Comment: have you considered using $_POST, if your first question is: "Do you like apples?" make sure that the "Yes" button has a name of Yes if they click no and you give the button a name of "No" you can do if($_POST['No']) { //show one question } else { //show another }

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, but I'm not using a button for each question.. in the Yes/No case it's a radio input. And there's only one  submit button at the end of the form.

Comment: You can give a radio button a name too...

Comment: sure but there are many questions of the same type (that depend on other questions) I can't use the name property.. there would be many inputs with the name Yes and No, also I can't use sth like Yes1 Yes2... because as I said the form could be different each time.

Comment: Well how do they do normal forms in real life? They give a different section a different number 'If 1 is not applicable to you skip to number 2, otherwise fill out number 1 and skip straight to number 3' it's simple if you think about it

Comment: see that's exactly the problem, I know it would be easy that way. But in my case all the sections/questions/choices are all dynamic and set by an admin, and there could even be many forms. which means I need a solution using variables only, an no specific names or id :( (Thank's for responding btw, really appreciate it)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the html5 `data-` attribute for some custom attributes to archive this:

html:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-dependid="test" />
<input type="text" data-dependid="test2" data-dependedid="test" data-dependedvalue="true" data-dependedtype="disabled" disabled="disabled" />
<input type="text" data-dependedid="test2" data-dependedvalue="input" data-dependedtype="disabled" disabled="disabled" />
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $("[data-dependid]").die().live("change keyup", function () {
        var that = this;
        var depends = $("[data-dependedid='" + $(that).attr("data-dependid") + "']");
        depends.each(function (i, depend) {
            var isSame = false;
            if (($(that).is(":checked") + "" == $(depend).attr("data-dependedvalue")) || ($(that).val() == $(depend).attr("data-dependedvalue"))) {
                isSame = true;
            }
            $(depend).attr($(depend).attr("data-dependedtype"), !isSame); //works for checked and disabled
        });
    });
});
```

This made the first textbox depend from the checkbox.

The second textbox depended from the value (input) of the first.

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gXdRm/2/)

To add a display option add this in the foreach:

```
var isSame = false;
if (($(that).is(":checked") + "" == $(depend).attr("data-dependedvalue")) || ($(that).val() == $(depend).attr("data-dependedvalue"))) {
    isSame = true;
}
if ($(depend).attr("data-dependendtype") == "display") {
    if (!isSame)
       $(depend).fadeOut();
    else
       $(depend).fadeIn();
}
else {
   $(depend).attr($(depend).attr("data-dependedtype"), !isSame);
}
```